# Validating JSON request at at time instead of one by one in WSO2 ESB

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-esb

My Requirement is to Validate the JSON iNPUT Request at a time instead of one by one.

ex: Say json fields
{

"firstname": "abcd",

"eid" : "566",

"zip" : "698"

}

ASSUME all my fields are wrong when i pass the request it should throw only firstname element , i need to throw all the three elements error at a time in wso2 esb, thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can create appropriate XSD schema for your message and use Validate mediator, or you can  create property for error message and concat all the error messages  you need, like

```
<property name="error" expression=""/>
<filter source="json-eval($.firstname)" regex="...your condition on first name">
   <then>
<property name="error" value="firstname is not valid!"/>
   </then>
   <else> 
   </else>
</filter>
<property name="error" expression=""/>
<filter source="json-eval($.eid)" regex="...your condition on eid">
   <then>
<property name="error" expression="fn:concat(get-property('error'),' eid is not valid!')"/>
   </then>
   <else> 
   </else>
</filter>
<filter source="json-eval($.zip)" regex="...your condition on eid">
   <then>
<property name="error" expression="fn:concat(get-property('error'),' zip is not valid!')"/>
   </then>
   <else> 
   </else>
</filter>
<filter source="get-property('error')" regex="^$">
   <then>

    ...sending error...

   </then>
   <else> 
   </else>
</filter>
```